# Multi style for checkbox and radio

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

I have this selectors in my CSS file:

```
input[type="checkbox"].checkbox {...}
input[type="checkbox"].checkbox + label {...}
input[type="checkbox"].checkbox:checked + label.blue {...}
```

This style my checkboxes, but now I want to style the checkboxes AND the radios. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: `input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]   {...}`

Comment: I think you would have to repeat it again with `[type="radio"]`. There's no way of performing *a logical or* in those selectors. Like this `input[type="checkbox"].checkbox:checked + label.blue, input[type="radio"].checkbox:checked + label.blue`

Comment: Use comma (,) to write your CSS code for the radio...